# Get php object defined in class to javascript in separate file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I haven't done much web development, to preface. I have a `methodExec.php` file and a `main.js` file. In my PHP file, I'm creating a list containing rows from a database and I'm trying to use that list in my .js file. I can access it if I declare the array outside of the class, but I'm not sure how to reference it after collecting the rows in the database.

methodExec.php

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/constants.php';

$methodExecVar = new methodExec();

class methodExec {
    private $conn;
    public $timesList;

    function __construct(){
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD, DB_TIMES) or 
                die('There was a problem with the database connection.');
    }

    function getTimes(){

        $timesList = [];
        $query = "SELECT *
                    FROM times";

        $result = $this->conn->query($query);

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $timesList[] = $row;
        }

        $this->conn->close();

        return $timesList;
    }
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">var jsArray = <?php echo json_encode($methodExecVar->timesList); ?>;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

main.js only includes `alert(jsArray)`. In this instance, it returns null, which I can understand, but I'm not sure how to make it wait or any alternatives. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the string being output properly in the script tag?

Comment: you can try js function setTimeout() for waiting for result. Try set it up to 300ms it should be ok.

Comment: it is probably null because browser load main.js to memory before jsArray inicialization. It may cause jsArray in alert is empty because does not exist in time call.

Comment: @daremachine  Where would I put setTimeout()?  Chris, which string are you referring to?

Comment: in main.js wrap alert() into timeout. It wait and call that variable later.

Comment: @daremachine For some reason, I tried it again as normal and it returns [Object object] [Object object] etc. Is this a race condition or is it working? Do I need to decode in order to get the actual object now?

Comment: alert always return [ object ] because it parse anything to string. If you want to see variable value you change alert to console.log() open console in browser dev tools and look

Comment: Ah, okay, I see what you mean. Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

It probably is `null` because the browser load main.js file to the memory before then the jsArray was initialized. It may cause jsArray empty because does not exist in time call.

The function what you want to call with jsArray variable you can wrap javascript function [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). Try set it up to 200-300ms It should be ok.
It will be call your function after that everything was initialized.

It is similar principle as jQuery.ready() function at jQuery library. It say's

*"Run the code only if the jQuery is in state ready."*